# I added 2 pounds of honey

Tags: beer

I brewed brewers best holiday ale on July 17th and I added 2 pounds of honey. I got 1.080 OG.
After 5 days no fermentation. 
I added yeast restarter but up to now no fermentation  .. I just checked the OG it's almost the same 1.070

What should I do now?

Comment: Do you mean 2 lbs (pounds) of honey? Or what is an "ib"?

Comment: Yes 2 pounds .. the abbreviation for the Pound is ib

Comment: The abbreviation for pound is 'lb" not "ib"... that's a lower case "L".

Comment: Thanks  .. lb ... it seems we have English language lesson here lol ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO *ALL* yeast should be made up into a starter culture prior to pitching. This is simply done using a clean bottle with a lid/cap. Sterilise the bottle with boiling water by filling it and leaving for a few minutes. Then empty the bottle (careful!) add a tablespoon or so of sugar or preferably dextrose and dissolve in a small amount of boiling water. This will sterilise the sugar. Then add cold water until the solution is "baby bath" hot. About 17-20 degreees. Pitch the yeast from the packet directly to the starter solution put on cap and shake vigorously to distribute and aerate the yeast. leave for 10 minutes and then shake vigorously again. Loosen but don't remove the cap to allow CO2 to escape. If the solution does not have a fine foamy head after 1 hour at 20 degrees then the yeast quality is suspect. Wait another hour or two to check again. If no real signs of fermentation in the starter bottle then discard and get fresh yeast. If all is foaming nicely - for example an inch or 2cm of fine foam on the top - then the yeast can be pitched into the wort and one can expect fermentation to happen.

Having said that I once had a stuck fermentation because I had mis-weighed the malt/suagrs to add to a brew. The sugar content of the wort was so high (OG over 1.090) that the yeast was inhibited. It worked, but very slowly. By adding sugar in lesser amounts and over time, the next brew was improved and fermented as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I'd pitch yeast again.  Quite often, the yeast in those kits can get old (they sit on the self so the yeast and hops aren't refrigerated).

Now, how can you mitigate this in the future?

1. When you get a kit home, put the yeast and hops in the refrigerator (you can put hops in the freezer without harm).
2. You can write down the ingredients in your brewing journal and buy them individually at your local brew shop so you know the yeast and hops have been treated well.
3. While this won't solve your immediate problem, if you moved up to brewing all grain recipes, you'd force yourself to buy your yeast from the cooler (and save money on ingredients).

Comment: Thanks a lot  ... do I have to activate the yeast & what's the best way to do that if I need ..

Comment: If you're using dry yeast, rehydrate (let it sit in the water for 10 minutes or so) in water that is the same temperature as your wort and pour it in.

Comment: I was waiting for your reply  .. ok I'll do that now ..  thank .. let's see